# SQL Last DateTime value

Tags: sql, datetime, ssms

I am trying to query some 'job' databases where I need the last datetime value for each operation_service in a given job. I also need to know whether the operation is complete or not.

```
SELECT Job.Job, Job_Operation.Operation_Service, Job_Operation.Sequence, 
MAX(Job_Operation_Time.Last_Updated) AS 'Last_Updated', Job_Operation_Time.Operation_Complete
FROM  Job_Operation 
LEFT JOIN Job ON Job.Job = Job_Operation.Job 
LEFT JOIN Job_Operation_Time ON Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation = Job_Operation.Job_Operation
WHERE Job.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY Job.Job, Job_Operation.Operation_Service, Job_Operation.Sequence, Job_Operation_Time.Last_Updated, Job_Operation_Time.Operation_Complete
ORDER BY Job.Job, Sequence
```

A snippet of some results here:

[image]

What I would like is a query that returns all the highlighted records but does not return the records with a red line through the job field.  NULL values are possible for both Operation_Complete and Last_Updated.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte  as
(
SELECT Job.Job, Job_Operation.Operation_Service, Job_Operation.Sequence, 
(Job_Operation_Time.Last_Updated) AS 'Last_Updated', Job_Operation_Time.Operation_Complete
,row_number()over(partition by Job_Operation.Operation_Service order by Job_Operation_Time.Last_Updated desc) rn
FROM  Job_Operation 
LEFT JOIN Job ON Job.Job = Job_Operation.Job 
LEFT JOIN Job_Operation_Time ON Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation = Job_Operation.Job_Operation
WHERE Job.Status = 'Active'
) select * from cte where rn=1
```